# Making 3rd array by combining the first two that are entered by user

Tags: c++, arrays

So if the 1st and the 2nd arrays have elements that are in not decreasing order, how can I make the 3rd one in the same not decreasing order? Here is my code but I don't know where exactly am I wrong in it:

```
int main() {
    int a[10], b[10];
    int m, n, i, j;
    cout << " Vavedete maks. broi el. za masiv 1: "; cin >> m;
    cout << " Vavedete maks. broi el. za masiv 2: "; cin >> n;
    cout << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        cout << " Vavedete " << i << " element za masiv 1: "; cin >> a[i];
    } cout << endl << endl;
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        cout << " Vavedete " << j << " element za masiv 2: "; cin >> b[j];
    }
    int c[20];
    int k;
    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    for (k = 0; k < (m + n); k++) {
        if (a[i]>b[j]) {
            c[k] = b[j];
            j++;
        }
        else {
            c[k] = a[i];
            i++;
        }
    }
    cout << " Noviyat masiv e: ";
    for (k = 0; k < (m + n); k++) {
        cout << c[k] << " ";
    } cout << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: in C++, use `std::vector`. And `std::sort()`.

Comment: I am really new to c++ so I am not in std yet :(

Comment: STL containers is somewhat advanced material, he's a beginner.

Comment: @Daniel he's already using `cin` and `cout`. Those are in the stdlib too. Declaring `vector<int> a(10);` is not harder than declaring `int a[10];`, and a lot of convenience comes with it.

Comment: `cin` and `cout` are standard input/output operations that are usually taught in the first class of a C++ course. Declaring `vector<int> a(10)` requires understanding of classes, generics, and functions, which comes much later in the course.

Comment: @Daniel In our school, they used to teach `vector` as **the** primary array type in C++. They probably did it well. We only learnt about primitive arrays later. "requires understanding of classes, generics, and functions" is wrong – it doesn't require the understanding of classes nor generics. `vector` can simply be regarded as a type. And **all** meaningful C++ code requires the understanding of functions, even the chunk OP has written. It's composed of a huge `main()` function.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (k = 0; k < (m + n); k++) {
    if (a[i]>b[j]) {
        c[k] = b[j];
        j++;
    }
    else {
        c[k] = a[i];
        i++;
    }
}
```

You're merging the arrays by comparing the current values and inserting the smaller value into `c`. But eventually you'll get to a point where `j >= n` or `i >= m`, meaning that you've inserted all the values of the `a` or `b` arrays into `c`. If `j >= n` then comparing `a[i] > b[j]` is undefined, because `j` is out-of-bounds.

Change your loop condition to `i < m && j < n`. Your  loop will then exit once *either* of the arrays has been completely inserted into `c`. At this point you can insert the rest of the other array:

```
for(; i < m; i++){
    c[k] = a[i];
    k++;
}

for (; j < n; j++){
    c[k] = b[j];
    k++;
}
```

Notice that only one of these loops will actually execute.